# Calculated column with today's date based on other columns

Tags: calculated-column

I've been struggling with the calculated column in SharePoint.

I would like to have a column in which the date is calculated from the values in two other columns. I have one column named "Status", a second column called "Requested Date" and a third column called "Lift Date".

If status is listed as "As Needed" or "Daily" I would like the Lift Date to show today's date, if the status shows "Not Started" then I would like Lift Date to show the Requested Date.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Today() or Now()
Above function also gives todays date

Comment: Today does not work in situations like this. Please read - http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/truth-about-using-today-in-calculated-columns/

Comment: More here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
=IF([STATUS]="Not Started", [Lift Date], [TodaysDate])
```

Today isn't allowed in calculated columns, but there are ways to work around that:

Create a "TodaysDate" column and run a daily SharePoint workflow that sets today's date and pauses for a day. Then you can reference that column for any calculated columns that you may have.

Comment: Thank you! This is so much easier and it appears to be working properly. I might have been overthinking how to go about the formula...

Comment: @Mike where is the value of [Today] configured?
Is it the regional settings we have in site administration or the settings we have in web application in central admin?

Comment: That is based on your regional settings in central administration

Comment: @Mike Mike Mike - did you read that blog post (mine actually) that you quoted from? You've misquoted it and its actually explaining why those techniques DONT work. For avoidance of doubt - this DOES NOT AND HAS NEVER WORKED.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, this was an older workaround in WSS, but was trying to get some reference for it. Guess we will have to use other means.

Comment: Hi Mike - it actually never worked properly, all the way back to WSS 2.0. There are lots and lots of blogs saying it does (and it appears to until you get to 'tomorrow' and [today] is now old) but it doesn't and never seems to have. All the best.

Comment: Christophe allready debunked this [TODAY] trick way back in 2008. There are workarounds for display a Today calculation in a **View**: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336