# Send alert when item gets to view

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, alert, view

I have a list with items and one of the column is a due date `{DueDate}`. I have a view, which displays items that are overdue (`{DueDate} <= [Today]`) that are assigned to a particular user `[Me]`. The `{DueDate}` column is calculated column - adding one year to another date from other column.

I have an alert which is sending emails when items from that view are modified.

Assuming the situtation that item is not showing in the view, because the Due Date condition is not met, but the next day the condition will be met (`{DueDate} <= [Today]`) and there will be no edit to the item, will I get alert message?

Basically will SharePoint send me an alert when item will show up in the view, but there was no edit to the item?

I hope the question is clear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Workflow to wait till the DueDate then send an email.

The Workflow approach is the Normal method

OR be abnormal

You can watch the Today calculation in a VIEW,
[How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

You could extend that code to update the item
like done in: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/Priority

This then would trigger the standard Alert process because the item was modified.

#### Update #1

See:
[Understanding Eventing Actions in SharePoint Designer 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj650894.aspx)

Comment: Considering workflow approach, what should I do when the date is edited and due date changes?

Comment: That would trigger another Workflow... and you need to write the Workflow so that the first-one started (on its 'due date') sees it should abort... ah... the joys of workflows

Comment: ;-) exactly, but I get the point. Thanks for your tips, I will go with a workflow most probably then as development options are limited to me.

Comment: I added a link to Microsoft docs in the reply, thanks for rating the answer, marking a answer will prevent it from popping up in unanswered lists... tnx.

Comment: Note: there are some risks with long-running workflows (this one would be running for a full year). If the server on which the workflow service runs is restarted during that year, the workflow may fail when it attempts to resume, and you'll only know if you go and check the workflow status. If {DueDate} changes after the workflow pauses (maybe they entered the intended due date into the column to which a year is added to *produce* {DueDate}, then later realized the error and corrected it), it won't resume based on the new value of {DueDate}; the resume date is set in stone when it pauses. etc.

Answer (score 0):

As long as condition is met,and you document lands in that specific view, you should be getting the alert, if its not you wont.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly,the calculated column gets updated only when the item is updated.So,there are no chance for the item to get into your view without any modification.

Comment: With a "today"-based view, it is not necessary for the calculated column to change in order for the item to switch from being "not in the view" to "in the view" - the comparison of the calculated column to "today" is done at the time you access the view.