# Calculated field not working SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calculated-column-formula

[image][image]I'm trying to create a calculated field in a workflow to send an email to an employee after 30 days. I set the calculation add 1 day (just for testing purposes so I don't have to wait 30 days) to the employee's start date, then email. In my workflow I have If CurrentItem:30DaySurvey equals Today, Email me but nothing emailed. Can someone see what I may be missing? My 2 screenshots attached.

Comment: Workflow is triggered when the item is being added or updated. I do not see how the sharepoint will know it has been 30days. You may want to consider writing a timer job or a powershell script that runs every night by a windows scheduled taks.

Comment: Oh there is more to the workflow and all of the stages work up until this stage. Sorry I should have entered the full thing. When the item is added the START DATE is automatically set as today's date-- so I thought this would work after 1 day. Seemed to me like it should have sent the email.

Comment: Instead of using "if `current item:100daysurvey` equals `Today`", you could try using "wait until `current item:100daysurvey` equals `today`"

Comment: I don't see wait as a condition. I'm just using SP Designer 2013? maybe Pause until Date?

Comment: Yes, use pause until date.

Comment: Indeed the Workflow option can only work with "Pause Until Date". For more see: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/156473/send-alert-when-item-gets-to-view and http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160426/create-unique-number-with-listitem-id-and-today-age-in-calculated-column-for

Comment: Yes, pause until date. Sorry, I should have bothered to look up the actual wording. Pause until date will let you still run the workflow on creation and on update, so if that date changes (for whatever reason) the workflow will still trigger at the correct time.

Answer (score 2):

If it will always be a 30 day period you could just use the "Pause for 30 days."   Have the workflow kick off on item creation, pause for 30 days, and then email.

Comment: That worked perfectly without the "equals today"-- thanks everyone for your guidance.