# Calculated column with nested IFs and comparisons

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I am working on an Aging report and my customer would like to group items by the following values: `0-30`, `31-60`, `61-90`, `90+`

I am creating a calculated column that will contain these values and let me group items for a view.

The following calculation works until I hit a callculation that is 61 or greater. In this case it displays `No` rather than `61-90` or `90+` as desired:

```
=IF(aging<31
    ,"0-30"
    ,IF(AND(aging>30,aging<61)
        ,"31-60"
        ,IF(AND(aging>60,aging<91)="61-90"
            ,IF(aging>90
                ,"90+"
               )
           )
       )
   )
```

The `aging` column is itself a calculated column which provides the age of an item `Today()-[Created]`. This is a column that was also requested.

Comment: so you are not able to use the 'aging' column in formula as its a calculated, is that your problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the syntax is incorrect in the IF statements.

Replace:

```
=IF(aging<31,"0-30",IF(AND(aging>30,aging<61),"31-60",IF(AND(aging>60,aging<91)="61-90",IF(aging>90,"90+"))))
```

with this:

```
=IF(aging<31,"0-30",IF(AND(aging>30,aging<61),"31-60",IF(AND(aging>60,aging<91),"61-90",IF(aging>90,"90+"))))
```

Change was replacing the `=` with a `,` in this section `IF(AND(aging>60,aging<91)="61-90"`

Comment: Just noticed.. :) right it was just syntax issue.. good catch @Jordan

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted your formula with line breaks and spaces, makes it easier to spot problems, you can safely copy/paste to SharePoint because they will be ignored.

Other poster allready noticed the error.

Note that your last IF does not have a *false* assigned either.. not an error.. but will default to *No* also.

Also note your **Today()** most likely does not do what you expect:

[How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)