# Date column with default value as calculated value that gives the next Wednesday

Tags: date-time, calculated-column-formula

I have a List Column that is Date only.  I would like it to default to the next Wednesday (or today if today is Wednesday).  What can I put in the `Calculated Value` field so that it defaults to Wednesday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`WEEKDAY()` function](https://support.office.com/en-SG/article/WEEKDAY-function-e5dbebc7-5818-48f8-90c0-7e7129e138d2) gives you a number of the day (sunday = **1**)

So Wednesday=4

Which makes your Calculated **Value** *Formula*:

```
=Today()  +  Weekday( Today() )-3
```

**Incorrect formula corrected by OP: `=TODAY()+MOD(11-WEEKDAY(TODAY()),7)`**

- You can use `Today()` in Calculated **Values**, Validation and View Filters.
  But in a Calculated Column **Formula** only updates when the Item is updated, so effectivly is the same as `Modified` (see: [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336))

More Functions at:

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: This will need a bit more work. If today is Tuesday, this calculated value would give you today + 2 - 3 = yesterday. Hint: you need a formula that always gives today plus 0 or more.

Comment: Thanks for getting me started: =TODAY()+MOD(11-WEEKDAY(TODAY()),7)