# How to add a DateNow or current Datetime in a calculated column field in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Is it posible to add a `DateNow` variable in the formula box in a calculated column? How?

Comment: Would Today be an option? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the accepted answer:

Stop linking to outdated and incorrect information about creating a [Today] column, linking to it and then deleting to it.

**It was allready explained in 2008 By Christophe it just does not work...**

For a complete explanation read: [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)