# sharepoint list color's?

Tags: list, sharepoint-online

I need something like this but in hours

[How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/163534)

can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

From the link you provided

```
var Days=Math.round((SPday.getTime()-new Date().getTime())/86400000);
```

That number is the number of milliseconds in a day:  **24 * 60 * 60 * 1000**

If in your part of the world a day has 24 hours I think it is: **60 * 60 * 1000**

```
var Hours=Math.round((SPday.getTime()-new Date().getTime())/3600000));
```

Note: you can also use scientific notation and prevent typos:

86400000 = 864e5

3600000 = 36e5

```
var Hours=Math.round((SPday.getTime()-new Date().getTime())/36e5));
```