# Filtered view of list based on Date compared to [Today]

Tags: calculated-column, date-time, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create a new view for my list that is filtered if the [Date] field is too far away.

T do this, I am tring to create a calculated column, "DaysAway" with something like this:

```
   =[Date] - [Today]
```

But I get this error:

> Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and
>   Me.

So then I could filter this in the view:

```
[DaysAway] < 7
```

How can I created a filtered view based on a Date's distance form [Today]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is why it does not work in a Calculated Column:

- [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

You can Filter by date in the View Filter settings,
This shows the Items created in the Last Week:

[image]

## Important:

You can use spaces (and linebreaks) in a Calculated Column Formula,
**but do NOT use spaces in this Filter Formula**

If you do, you get the most informative message:

[image]