# Getting less than (Today+7) days items using caml query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I want to retrieve items from list which are lessthan seven days from today date.

**Today date**:12/14/2015

**seven days means**: 12/21/2015.

Using caml query. can anybody know please tell me.

Comment: C# or jquery ??

Answer (score 20):

In a caml query, you will need to use `<Today>` token with `OffsetDays`.

For e.g.

```
<Where><Leq><FieldRef Name='Your_Date_Column' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='7' /></Value></Leq></Where>
```

Reference: [Using the Today token in a CAML query](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2009/06/using-today-token-in-caml-query.html)

Answer (score 5):

Let SharePoint do the work for you

You can Filter by date in the View Filter settings,
This shows the Items created in the Last Week:

[image]

## Important:

You can use spaces (and linebreaks) in a Calculated Column Formula,
**but do NOT use spaces in this Filter Formula**

If you do, you get the most informative message:

[image]

Comment: But if any items gets updated later week again this calculated date will get updated.

Comment: This is not a Calculated Column/Field. It is a View Filter calculation, executed every time you open the View. You can put references to Calculated Columns here, but you [can not use Today in a Calculated Column](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

Comment: FYI. Today can be used in calculated columns. I have used it several time.. just you cannot use it simply like  above

Answer (score 2):

Use following code if using jquery:

```
var lastWeek = new Date();

lastWeek.setDate(lastWeek.getDate() + 7);
```

now you can use this variable the way you want. I hope this is what you were in need

Answer (score 1):

```
objQuery.Query = "<Query><Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='7' /></Value></Geq><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Title' /></IsNotNull></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' /> </OrderBy></Query>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The Query where we can view the current week seems to be as below:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
     <DateRangesOverlap>
       <FieldRef Name='EventDate'/><FieldRef Name='EndDate'/>
       <Value Type='DateTime'>
           <Week/> 
       </Value>
     </DateRangesOverlap>
  </Where>
</Query
```