# Number of Days Outstanding

Tags: 2010

[image]How to calculate number of outstanding days in SharePoint? I've been using the formula below but it is not stable

```
=IF([Document Status]="",TODAY()-[Initiated On]+1,[Date Reviewed]-[Initiated On])
```

Comment: what is the output you are receiving? Information you have provided is not sufficient to resolve the issue. What is it not stable, if block or else block

Comment: Sometimes calculated output display incorrect.

Comment: **When a Document Status is empty you want to display the number of days it is outstanding** As explained in an answer below, you can not use the TODAY() function like this, because it is only evaluated when the Item is updated (thusacts the same as using [Modified]

Comment: I need a column that will start counting the number of day base on "Initiated On" value and the counting should stop once column "Date Reviewed" is provided. I've tried the formula provided earlier and it work but somehow other values are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas will only update when the List Item is modified/updated.

That means `Today()` is the same as `[Modified]` (last date the item was modified)

For long explanation and possible workarounds read:

[How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

Answer (score 0):

You can display outstanding days using CSR (Client Side Rendering).

The conventional way is to write JS code and inject it in the library view. More details here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

A quicker way to customize a specific library view is Cisar: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en