# Sharepoint Online - Calculated Column & Conditional Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I'm trying to create a tracking list to track the status of jobs using SharePoint Online.

I want to use the categories:

```
'In Progress' = 7 days + from Due Date
'Requires Action' = Within 7 days from Due Date
'Close Out' = After Due Date
```

I have set up conditional formatting using Content Editor - Web Part. I am now trying to set up a 'Status' column that returns the correct outcome based on a time frame.

I have the following formula:

```
=IF(Date+7<[Due Date],"In Progress","")&IF([Due Date]<=Date,"Close Out","")
```

**Note**: Date = Today's date

This delivers the desired results for 'In Progress' and 'Close Out', however I am uncertain as to how to deliver the 'Requires Action' outcome between the two time periods. What should I add to the formula?

Comment: If i understand you correctly you simply want a different string if between the two dates. Simply do a >= and <= in one if statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Roland - how exactly should I add that to my formula above? I've tried but it keeps returning an error.

Comment: Try this: =IF([Due Date]>TODAY()+7,"In Progress",IF([Due Date]<=TODAY(),"Close Out","Requires Action"))

Comment: Thought I would mention that calculated columns work (for the most part) just like excel functions. To quickly make a new formula simply test it in excel which is much quicker to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it as the following example in my SharePoint 2013 on-prem.

**If you want to use the today() date, the formular looks like this:**

```
=IF(AND([Due Date]>Today(), [Due Date]<Today()+7), "Requires Action", "")&IF(Today()+7<[Due Date],"In Progress", "")&IF([Due Date]<=Today(),"Close Out", "")
```

And my list looks e.G. like this:

[image]

Keep in mind, that the today() doesn't work as you might expect. See [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336).

**With seperate date column my list looks like this:**

[image]

The column settings are:

> Title -> Single line of text
>
> Date -> Date only (Not required if using today())
>
> Due Date -> Date only
>
> Status -> calculated column (returned as single line of text)

The fomular I used in the status column is:

```
=IF(AND([Due Date]>[Date], [Due Date]<[Date]+7), "Requires Action", "")&IF([Date]+7<[Due Date],"In Progress", "")&IF([Due Date]<=[Date],"Close Out", "")
```

If this helps you you can give it a *vote up* or if it fit's perfectly you can accept it as your *answer*.

Comment: Also, while using this trick I wrote a system.update powershell script. This would update all the items daily thus updating the today() date.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas will only update when the List Item is modified/updated.

That means `Today()` is the same as `[Modified]` (last date the item was modified)

For long explanation and possible workarounds read:

[How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167384/number-of-days-outstanding/167386#167386). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!

Comment: Then I choose to not answer at all. Why should I put more and more effort into it if no-one searches before asking

Comment: Or add it as a comment, in this case I guess you just want to spread the knowledge about the workings of  `Today()`, not answer the full question. Comments are great for that :)