# Count not updating in calculated column

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am getting number of days between Created & Now in SharePoint 2010 list using calculated column by below mentioned formula.

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(NOW(),Created,"d")),DATEDIF(Created,NOW(),"d"))
```

It gets me the correct value.

But the problem is that the counts are not updating on regular basis.

**e.g.**

Imagine that i had created item in list before 5 days & if i create calculated column using above formula than it will give me correct count (5) but if i go to list on next day than it is showing me the same count. It is not updating to 6.

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: You have not searched for previous answers: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

Create one **Calculated** column and set data type return from formula as **Number**. Apply below formula:

```
="<img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' onload=""{"
&" var day=new Date();"&" var SPday=new Date(); "
&"  SPday.setFullYear("&YEAR(Created)&","&MONTH(Created)-1&","&DAY(Created)&");"
&" var m = Math.ceil(Math.abs(SPday.getTime()-day.getTime()) /(1000*3600*24)); "
&" this.parentNode.innerHTML= m ;"
&"}"">"
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: I had tried the same & it is working fine for me... Thanks Dikesh Gandhi

Comment: Welcome.....always happy to help ;)

Answer (score 7):

#### Calculated Formulas are only modified/updated when an Item Changes

Read that one more time:

#### Calculated Formulas are only modified/updated when an Item Changes

Got it?

That means the Today/Now function will
get you the result from: the **LAST item update**.

SharePoints Today/Now functions do **not** behave the same as in Excel.

You can force such an update with:

- Changing the Formula *that's why most people **think** Today()/Now() works*
- Changing (any value of) the Item:

  - With a Workflow
  - or Code (.Net or JavaScript)

Long explanation, workarounds an bag of tricks at:

[How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

Answer (score 3):

Values in calculated columns are not dynamic. They are recalculated when list item is updated.