# Calculated field question

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, calculated-column-formula

Currently working on documents with status and expiration date and created 2 columns in SharePoint I want the status column to automatically tell me if the document  is current or expired. The formula I have so far is `=IF([Today]>[Expiration Date],"Expired", "Current")` but I am getting an error "Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me"

Anyway to fix this? response is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula you can use in the calculated field (Status):

Set the Data Type of the column to *Number* and add this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Expiration Date]),"No Expiration",
"<img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' onload=""{"
&"var date=new Date();"
&"date.setFullYear("
&YEAR([Expiration Date])&","
&MONTH([Expiration Date])-1&","
&DAY([Expiration Date])&");"
&"var DaysDiff=Math.round((date.getTime()-new Date().getTime())/86400000);"
&"this.parentNode.innerHTML=((DaysDiff<=0)?'Expired':'Current');"
&"}"">")
```

### UPDATE

CSR to fix the HTML output on DispForm.aspx:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
  function getBaseHtml(ctx) {
    return SPClientTemplates["_defaultTemplates"].Fields.default.all.all[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType][ctx.BaseViewID](ctx);
  }
  function init() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      Templates: {
           Fields: {
               "Status": {
                   DisplayForm: function(ctx) { return ctx.CurrentItem["Status"]; },
               },
           },
      },
      ListTemplateType: 101
    });
  }
  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/HTML2TextCSR.js"), init);
  init();
});
```

---

Comment: Daniel, It works just what i wanted.. However when  viewing the item in the form view the status column is showing the formula and not the  " expired" or "current" wording . Anything i need to change?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You can fix that with the CSR script.

Comment: do i need sharepoint designer to enter these script?

Comment: No need for SPD. Create a new file called 'HTML2TextCSR.js'. Copy the CSR code into it. Then upload the file to '~siteCollection/Style Library/' (don't forget to check-in/publish [if required]). Go to your DispForm.aspx, edit the page, edit the form web part, put '~siteCollection/Style Library/HTML2TextCSR.js' into the JS Link property. Save the page and then check it out, the HTML should be gone.

Comment: You could also use the Cisar Extension for Chrome to deploy the CSR

Comment: Great! Would you please mark it as answer?

Comment: Yes it is.. works well!

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed but there is tricky workaround for this.

1. Open up the List Settings page where you want this column.
2. Create column named “Today”.
3. Now create the calculated column where you need to use current date
   within formula and add “Today” from available columns
4. Once this is done, we no longer need that our own generated column
   “Today” so you can delete it (Although when you need to edit formula
   you will need this again, so either recreate this dummy Today field
   or make it hidden using code behind. Otherwise SharePoint will put
   you again on that error screen).

Read Complete Post here: [Use [Today] and [Me] in Calculated Column](https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/)

Comment: I like the way we cheat SharePoint :) :)

Comment: :) we have sharp mind in this small world, who always looks for the workaround. i think this cheat deserve upvote.

Comment: Hi Waqas, check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column . It says we should not use this trick as this trick never works.

Comment: Your are only cheating yourself, that [TODAY] column trick does not work, never worked and will never work. Explanation see: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336

Comment: i tried but im returning a value of 12/30/1899. does it work with sharepoint 2010?