# SharePoint views - Filtering by date and time

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, filter, view, date-time

We have a custom web-part that uses a View to filter Procurements (Tenders) by date.

We are trying to filter the view using the **[Today]** function but from what I gathered it *only uses the Date* and disregards the Time, which is an annoyance since Tenders have opening and closing times.

From a little bit of research I found out that [Now] does not exist in SharePoint and has to be implemented through code or workflows, which is out of the question for our company since we are using custom branding for our infrastructure (we have a farm and give portals to clients for which they manage the content).

Is there any method how we can filter by **Date & Time** with minimal modifications?

Comment: Different approach but requires some javascript: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best solution I found:

Suppose you have a Date and Time column named "StartDate", add a calculated column with the following formula to extract the time:

```
TEXT(StartDate-DATE(YEAR(StartDate),MONTH(StartDate),DAY(StartDate)),"h:mm")
```

You will get the time extracted with the `hh:mm` format, and you can do your filter based on the two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `[Today]` doesn't include the time value, so the values in the background are like this:

```
[Today] = 40,024 (Serial date value)
[Start Date] = 40,024.604166667 (Serial date + time value)
```

This means that you can't check the Time using `[Today]`

The easiest, yet not recommended solution would be modifying the view in SPD.

Follow this short guide: [Filtering views by Time and Date](https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2008/04/24/filtering-views-by-time-and-date/)

Answer (score 0):

Modify view on behalf of created field under Filter option & set logic there

Comment: Welcome to community, when you provide answer or solution to some question make sure you describe it well for others and can add some code parts or web reference. your answer here looks more like comment than answer. Please update your answer.