# Using actual Dates to calculate a list column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, list, column, calculated-column

We are on SharePoint 2013 externally and Office 365. I am trying to make a calculated column to filter a list on specific dates but it keeps error. Is it possible to calculate on dates such as `Between 01/04/2016 AND 31/08/2016` ?

Comment: are you want to filter list by date range?

Comment: Do you want to filter the list? Also what is formula that you are using and getting error

Comment: Intan As above I want to make a formula in a column to result in yes or no using any actual dates but not using today. yes to filtering on a date range

Comment: Gaurravs I put the formula there in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter some elements of the list, then You can `create a view` with some `filters`, that are based on a date.

This article can also be helpful`

> [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column)

Comment: Marcin O I wish to use actual dates in a calculated column because I can then change the dates to suit