# Default date to the next Tuesday

Tags: date-time, default-value

I used this formula

```
=TODAY()+MOD(10-WEEKDAY(TODAY()),7)
```

in a calculated field which seems to work. However, as `TODAY` is actually **Tuesday, Sept 13**, I need the date to reflect next **Tuesday, Sept 20**.

So, from Tue (Sep 13) to Mon (Sep 19), I need the date to default to Sep 20, and so on.

How do I adjust the formula to do that?  Thanks!

Comment: You should be aware of TODAY() never work at Calculated Column for more details check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear - I've used a date/time column and added the formula noted above to the Calculated Value field within the Default Value area of the column setup

Comment: Adding an if statement allowed me to get the results needed:     =IF((TODAY()+MOD(10-WEEKDAY(TODAY()),7))=TODAY(),TODAY()+MOD(10-WEEKDAY(TODAY()),8),TODAY()+MOD(10-WEEKDAY(TODAY()),7))

Answer (score 1):

In case if it's not possible to get it done using a formula it's possible to achieve it using an event receiver.  Write a piece of c# code inside the itemAdded event to calculate the next Tuesday and update the field.

Comment: thanks for responding, however, I am NOT techy enough to even begin to know how to do what you've stated