# Calculate 14 days or less on Expiry Date column from Todays date

Tags: calculated-column

I have a library with a column 'Expiry Date'. I wish to create an additional column to advise the user if a particular entry needs to be reviewed.

The parameters for this is if the 'Expiry Date' is 14 days or less from Todays' date.

In the filter I understand you can't use [Today] and have tried the workarounds but without much luck.

I'm fairly new to calculated columns so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Calculated formula should be like:

```
=IF([ExpiryDate]-14 <= NOW(),"Expired","Not Expired")
```

Comment: Many thanks Ronak. I have tried the above formula and although works in principle, still not quite what I was after. i.e. I have an Expiry Date of 28th Nov 2016 which is saying Not Expired which is correct, but I would only wish to show items in the list with an Expiry Date of 14 days or less from current date. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: If you want to show only those items which are expired then create list view & filter with 'CalculatedColumn1' is equal to 'Expired'

Comment: So if I have an Expiry Date of say 31 Dec 2016 showing. How do I go about ensuring in that list only Todays Date (i.e. 06th October) up to 20th October is only refelcting. i.e. NOW()+14.

Comment: means ? have you created view with filter on calculated column ? ,.. then only expired items will be shown..

Comment: Remember: Today and Now in Calculated Formulas do NOT auto update: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336

Answer (score 0):

My question to you is, are you trying to just filter out anything that expired in the last 2 weeks?, or do you want to actually change the status of those items in a separate column?

If you are *only* looking to hide them from view, in the filter section of the View Settings...

**Show the items when column:**

`Expiry Date` | `is  less than` | `[Today]`

**AND**

`Expiry Date` | `is  greater than or equal to` | `[Today]-14`

This is a view not a calculated column, so there is no "Status" column identifying the item as 'Expired', they simply will not show.

If you want a column that specifically labels items as 'Expired' you can use a Power Automate Flow:

1. Add a new column with name Status, type Single Line of text, and default value of 'Active' or 'Not Expired' or whatever you want
2. Create a Scheduled Flow set to run at 12:15am every 1 day
3. Add action **Get Items**, set the Site Name and List Name and type into the ODATA Filter: "Expiry_x0020_Date lt "
4. Use the expression builder and enter: "formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')"; click Add to add the date information as a variable that will update daily; this will grab all items with Expiry Date *before* today.
5. Add action Update Item; set the Site Name and List Name; and use the dynamic content button to select the ID from the Get Items action; this will cause the Get Items action to be encapsulated in a For Each container
6. Expand the Advanced Parameters and for the Status field, enter `Expired`
7. Add action Terminate

Save.  Your flow is now ready to go and will update the Status field for all items with an Expiry Date before today to Expired at 12:15am every day.  You can manually trigger the flow by running a test and that will also change over all of the currently expired ones.

You can then create a list view to include or exclude items that are Expired, and/or use Conditional Formatting to highlight them.

If you want other options on your Status field, you can:

- Set the type to Choice
- Create the list of choices, and a default value
- Add "Status ne [replace with excluded status]" to your ODATA Filter; this will cause the Get Items action to ignore that status

You can use the steps above as a foundational framework for setting up additional updates and ODATA filters to change the Status, or other fields based on date.

Hope this helps, sorry its a few years late.

**Helpful Links:**

- [Get Started with Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/getting-started)
- [Need help with odata filter syntax and UTCNow() expression](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Need-help-with-odata-filter-syntax-and-UTCNow-expression/td-p/891318)
- [Format a column to change how it looks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-a-column-to-change-how-it-looks-6ed2f787-0e9e-4908-b861-0d06571c256d)