# How to make SharePoint designer workflow not to start if a column change?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

We have two SP Designer workflow attached to a list such as "WF1" and "WF2". "WF1" will update a particular column daily. "WF2" will trigger for item changed event. Now I want to stop triggering of "WF2" when "WF1" update the particular column daily. How to achieve this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a semaphore [that's what oldskool programmers called it in the previous century]

Create an extra [previous_currentdate]

Let WF1 update [currentdate]

Then WF2 kicks in, if the 2 are not equal you know WF1 just ran

Let WF2 always set [previous_currentdate] to [currentdate]

If you want Today calculations only in a View, you *could* do without WF1:
[How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details on both Workflows but be specific on WF2 and tell us what it's purpose and why can't you have one workflow instead of two?

Comment: WF1 is used to update calculated field daily (currentdate) and WF2 is usual approval workflow.