# Calculated Field Formula with IF AND

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-list

Trying to get this calculated column value to work and having trouble with the syntax:

```
=IF(AND([Due Date]<=[Today],ISBLANK([Release Date])),"Yes", "No")
```

Pretty much if "Due Date" is less than or equal today and "Release Date" is blank then show "Yes" otherwise "No".

Comment: What is your question? Have you entered the formula? Have you seen the error message that calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today? What are you asking us to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your Calculated Column syntax is correct.

and could be shortened to:

```
=AND( [Due Date]<=[Today] , ISBLANK([Release Date]) )
```

**BUT**

[Today] does **not** behave like it does in Excel;
it will always be the date the Item **was last touched**

[How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=AND( [Due Date]<=[Today()] , ISBLANK([Release Date]) )
```