# Formula syntax error

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to add more than one if's (also) statements inside a formula, but it is not working because of a syntax error. What I'm trying to do is if actual sign date column is less or equal to the expected date column (both date fields), to change the color in green, else to be blue-ish.

Also I'm trying to add into that same formula if the column named 'Confirmation Read And Agreed' is blank (empty) and the expected sign date is less than the date column set to today's date 'Today' (basically if expected sign date is overdue), to bring me a red color on that column. Do please have a look at the formula below.

```
=IF([Actual Sign Date]<=[Expected Sign Date]
    ,"<div style= 'background-color:#00CC00;'>"
        &[Actual Sign Date]
        &"</div>"
    ,"<div style= 'background-color:#00ffff;'>"
        &[Expected Sign Date]
        &"</div>"
    ,IF(ISBLANK[Confirmation Read And Agreed]
           &&
              [Expected Sign Date]<[Today]
       ,"<div style= 'background-color:#FF0000;'>"
           &[Confirmation Read And Agreed]
           &"</div>"
       )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Today in a Formula is a never ending story: [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

I reformatted your Formula with line breaks.

2 errors I see at first glance:

- First IF is not closed with ) so you add a fourth parameter
- SharePoint does not do an && **operator**, you need an AND **function**

See: http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Tip: **always** edit Formulas in a decent Text Editor, SharePoint will remove the linebreaks on copy/paste/save

The FunctionList page also helps you to a Bookmarklet to aid with editing:

[image]

Comment: Hi Danny!I edited the code like you said, but it still doesn't accept it due to a syntax error.Here's the edited code, any ideas how to write the following in a way, so it could be accepted=IF([Actual Sign Date]<=[Expected Sign Date],"<div style= 'background-color:#00CC00;'>"&[Actual Sign Date]&"</div>","<div style= 'background-color:#00ffff;'>"&[Expected Sign Date]&"</div>",IF(ISBLANK([Confirmation Read And Agreed])AND[Expected Sign Date]<[Today],"<div style= 'background-color:#FF0000;'>"&[Confirmation Read And Agreed]&"</div>"))

Comment: Then trim it down, and build it step by step

Comment: OK Danny, thank you very much! Made what I was asking for and wanted, but the easier and not as complicated way with JS and JQuery. Have a great day!

Comment: Yes, some people find jQuery easier than SharePoint.. The new Microsoft way is React..

Comment: Haven't worked with React, but intending to learn and work with it in the future.