# Add a line break in calculated field with formatted date?

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create a line break within a calculated column that displays the Date in DD MM YY format.  The purpose is to utilize the field in a script which is altering the list view.   My calculated column entitled Date contains this:

```
=TEXT(Created, "dd mm yy")
```

I know it's possible to render HTML if I change the data type to a Number.  However, I don't really need the HTML to render in the list, ideally I just want it to render in plain text like so:

```
"DD <br/> MM <br/> YY".
```

If I add the 
 within the current code, I get something like:  <6r>DD<6r>MM<6r>YY.   Not sure why the b is being turned into a 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wit your Formula

```
=TEXT(Created, "dd mm yy")
```

You provide 2 parameters to the TEXT( ) function,
telling it to format (replace with values) Created with the format: "dd mm yy"

The output is: **day month year**

```
"11 12 16"
```

The TEXT() function was modeled after (but is not the same), the Excel TEXT () Function,
fairly good documented in the [Text Function Examples Excel Sheet](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/8/6A818B0B-06F4-4E41-80DE-D383A3B89865/TEXT%20function%20examples.xlsx)

So characters in the format string have special meaning

I don't know Why **b** is converted, but with

```
=TEXT(Today()-365, "b")
=TEXT(Today(), "b")
=TEXT(Today()+365, "b")
```

it is fair to say it is the two digit Year

Interesting to note is that **y** is the same as **yy**
And the SharePoint TEXT() function does not care about upper/LOWER case

To exclude characters from being formatted you have to escape them with a slash: **\**

```
=TEXT( Today() ,"dd mm yyyy \# DDD DD MMMM YYYY")
 &"<br>"
 &TEXT(TODAY(),"\b:b \d:d \h:h \m:m \s:s \y:y")
 &TEXT(TODAY(),"\<\B\R>\B:B \D:D \H:H \M:M \S:S \Y:Y")
```

Outputs:
[image]

b - year (but why?)
d - day
y - year

h- hours = 0 because Today() has no timestamp
m - minutes
s- seconds

To make the <BR> work as a Line Break you have to output the Text as HTML by setting its field output to anything BUT Text (it is a trick)

Number will align the text to the right (because it is supposed to be a Number),
Set it to DateTime to have the text Left Aligned

Note, I used Today() as an example, be aware it does **NOT** recalculate every day like it does in Excel:   The Formula is only updated when the Item changes, so Today() is effectively the same as Modified (without the time stamp!)
See [https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336?s=1|0.0000#151336](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336?s=1%7C0.0000#151336)

Most basic Excel functions are the same in SharePoint,
see:

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: Thanks for the details, however this didn't really answer my question.  I already know all of this.  I indicated  I currently have my Date column with a Number data type.  I don't need it parsed as HTML, I just need it parsed as plain text with the date formatted as I indicated above.  Adding a forward slash still renders the weird <16r>.   I am looking for the correct syntax [or if it's possible to even do this].  Thanks for your input all the same.

Comment: I explained why you should use a **backslash**, not a forward slash: ``=TEXT(Created,"dd <\br/> mm <\br/> yy") ``. If you want to render the <br/> as text you have to set it to Single Line of Text, as anything else will make the Browser interpret it as HTML

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I think got overwhelmed by all the examples.  This works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Cool, mark it as answer so you gain more StackOverlfow priviledges, an onto your next question.