# Formula in Calculated field is correct but doesn't refresh

Tags: calculated-column-formula

A calculated field has been created within my Sharepoint library to show what items will be due for review within 21days of the current date. I understand the [Today] [Now] don't work too well within Sharepoint, and wondering if anyone can provide assistance. Current formula is

```
=IF(
     AND( [Expiry Date]-NOW()>=0 , [Expiry Date]-NOW()<=21 )
     ,"Expiring Soon"
     ,"Effective"
   )
```

The return of the information is correct, but as the title advises, it doesn't refresh unless I go into the formula, copy and paste it back in and Save.

Answer (score 3):

Because SharePoint is **not** Excel,

And Formulas are only re-calculated when an Item changes or when the Formula itself is changed.

[How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `JSLink` instead of Calculated field.

Reference link for use of JSLink in SharePoint:
http://www.kaptyn.com/SharePoint/client-side-rendering-2013/