# The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported

Tags: calculated-column

I'm trying to add a column to a table I created in SharePoint. I want the column to do the following:
Given the status of an action e.i. due or over due,  calculate the number of days that the action has been raised. So I wrote a formula to calculate this taking the values from the column Date Raised and today's date.

```
=IF(OR([Status]="Overdue",[Status]="Due"),DATEIF([Date Raised],[Today],"d"))
```

When I click the OK button I get

> Sorry, something went wrong The formula contains a syntax error or is
>   not supported

I would appreciate if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I read other posts and I managed to solve the problem. By using today() the formula would be:

=IF(OR(Status="Overdue",Status="Open"),(TODAY()-[Date Raised]),"")

It worked perfectly throughout the entire table

Comment: Note that the Today( ) function does not do what you want it to do (update every day): http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336

Answer (score 0):

**Using the Today() Function is exactly the same as using [Modified]**

Because SharePoint Formulas only re-calculate the Formula when:

- the Item is updated
- or the Formula itself is edited

So you daily check does not work.

Details and workarounds to do Today calculations in Views: [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)