# SharePoint Calculated column to Check If today is 14th date

Tags: calculated-column, date-time

I have date time column called **Today**.

I'm trying to create calculated column which check today is 14

Value for **Today** column is **4/13/2017**
I m trying to check that is today is 14. means like this (**4/14/2017**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that SharePoint is NOT Excel, so Formulas do not update Date calculations

- [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column)

Formula:

```
=DAY( [DateTime] )
```

gets you the day number

```
=IF( DAY( [DateTime] )=14 , "It is the 14th" , "Not the 14th" )
```

All Functions: http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List