# Filter "Modified" by previous week

Tags: list-view, calculated-column-formula, date

Want to filter list items that were modified on last week

Think pseudocode for this will be 
Modified >= ( [Today]-WEEKDAY-7 )  &&  Modified <= ( [Today]-WEEKDAY )

No matter what day of week is today, we need items from previous week:

[image]

So as I understand I need to create calculated fields

**Previous_Week_StartDate**:  =[Today]-WEEKDAY-7

and

**Previous_Week_EndDate**:  =[Today]-WEEKDAY

and then filter view like

Modified >= Previous_Week_StartDate   and   Modified <= Previous_Week_EndDate

But when I use something like '=WEEKDAY([Today])' in calculated column I get errors. Somebody did something like this?

**upd.:** I can also create View programmatically (with custom CAML query), but don't know how to construct such query

**upd.2:** Resolved. It was easier: created two calculated fields(return type as Date):

> **StartWeek**, formula:
>
> =Modified-(WEEKDAY(Modified)-1)
>
> **EndWeek**:
>
> =StartWeek+7

and created filter in views:

[image]

So I compare intervals from Sunday to Sunday (think it depends on Your Regional settings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's normal, You should be aware of the [`Today`] and [`ME`] can't be used in the Calculated Field, Please check all details and alternative solution at

[How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column)

Meanwhile, In your view, you can use filter directly to filter the files  modified within the last 7 days as

[image]

Comment: Thank You for provided link!  Uff.. I thought it is much easier with calculated columns.. Already used [Today]-7, but need only previous week.. Will try to use caml and create this view programmatically

Comment: you are welcome @GennadyG , in my opinion, the easier method depnd on your requirment , meanwhile the OOTB filter option may be help, so Could you please try to filter modified is greater than [Today]-7 and and less than [Today]. I am sorry if I am confused to understand your mean so please inform me what is the difference between last 7 days and last week !

Comment: Oh, my english not native so I confused You. I mean 'previous week', so if today we have May 11, we need results between 1 May - 7 May. If tomorrow we have 12 May, we still need results between 1 May and 7 May (because it was previous week)

Comment: Okay, Now it's clear let's search together for the best solution to achieve that  :)