# How do I add hours to Now() after converting it to a text value?

Tags: date-time, calculated-column-formula, timezone

I have a calculated field that shows the text value of the current hour, so I'm using:

```
=TEXT(Now(), "hh")
```

Unfortunately, it's showing this value in Pacific time, so I'd like to add 3 hours to display the value as if it were Eastern time. In the past, I've used a formula that adds hours to a date/time field like this:

```
=Now()+(3/24)
```

So I combined the syntax like this:

```
=TEXT(Now()+(3/24), "hh")
```

Unfortunately, it does not seem to work. I get some really odd 2 digit number and not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Can this be done?

Comment: If the answer was helpful could you remove it from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Answer (score 3):

As `Now()` returns a full formated date-time-stamp, I believe you should add hours by using `divide a day by 24 hours by 60 minutes multiplied the amount of hours in minutes` formula. In this case, it would be `(1/24/60*180)` as 3 hours = 180 minutes.

By the way, that should not require the use of `=TEXT`, so a complete calculcated column would be `=Now()+(1/24/60*180)`.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track,

A SharePoint DateStamp is the number of **days** since 1/1/1900

So 3 hours is indeed 3/24

```
=Text( Now()      , "m/d/y hh:mm" )   // now

=Text( Now()+3/24 , "m/d/y hh:mm" )   // 3 hours ahead
```

#### **But you might have another problem!**

`now` behaves the same as the infamous SharePoint `Today`

See: [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

**it does not update**!!!!  SharePoint is not Excel

> Because Formulas are only recalculated when the Item is updated
>   or when you change the Formula itself

Read and understand that one more time:

> Because Formulas are only recalculated when the Item is updated
>   or when you change the Formula itself

**That means:**

With:

```
=Text( Now()+3/24 , "hh" )   // hours
```

If you wait an Hour and press F5 refresh in a View, **the values are never updated**

**because the Formula executed an hour (or longer) ago**
when you changed the Item or updated the Formula itself

See: [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)