# Calculated Column in Sharepoint with IF statements

Tags: calculated-column

I would like to use two formulas to define the field 'Age'.

1. If the column 'Date Project is Completed/Cancelled' is populated, 
   then Age = 'Date Project is Completed/Cancelled' - 'Date Assigned'
2. If the column 'Date Project is Completed/Cancelled' is not populated,
   then Age = 'Current Date' - 'Date Assigned'

This is the formula I used but SharePoint will not accept:

```
=IF(ISBLANK ([Date Project is Completed/Cancelled]), [Current Date] - [Date Assigned], [Date Project is Completed/Cancelled] - [Date Assigned])
```

Answer (score 1):

See all answers at: [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column)

You can **not** do Current Date calculations in a Calculated Column

---

The comparison part of your IF is with the OR function:

```
=IF( OR( [Date Project]="Completed" , [Date Project]="Cancelled"), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: I can use e.g. Today() + 30 in the calculated column, am I missing anything?

Comment: You are missing a lot, read that [How to use Today post...](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column) for the longer explanation **Calculated Formulas are only modified/updated when an Item Changes (or the Formula is updated)** ... so what is the value when you wait 24 hours?