# Calculated Field Syntax Error - Matrix Output

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column-formula, calculated-column

I'm quite new to this, could anyone point out why my calculated field isn't working

Im trying to use a matrix to output a value of critical, high, medium or low

The field Im using is ImpUrg_Total, this is my current failure

```
=IF(ImpUrg_Total<2,"Critical",IF(AND([ImpUrg_Total]>=2,[ImpUrg_Total]<4,"High",IF(AND([ImpUrg_Total]>=4,[ImpUrg_Total]<9,"Medium",IF([ImpUrg_Total]=>9,"Low"))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your formula like the following:

```
=IF(ImpUrg_Total<2,"Critical",IF(AND([ImpUrg_Total]>=2,[ImpUrg_Total]<4),"High",IF(AND([ImpUrg_Total]>=4,[ImpUrg_Total]<9),"Medium",IF([ImpUrg_Total]=>9,"Low"))))
```

Similar issue post for your reference:

1. [SharePoint 2013 calculated column adding multiple if statement](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218662/sharepoint-2013-calculated-column-adding-multiple-if-statement)
2. [Calculated Column with Nested IF statments](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36237/calculated-column-with-nested-if-statments)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it still didn't like it but was a lot closer, I changed it slightly to add in <13 as it will never be 13 or more so it worked like this

Comment: =IF(ImpUrg_Total<2,"Critical",IF(AND(ImpUrg_Total>=2,ImpUrg_Total<4),"High",IF(AND(ImpUrg_Total>=4,ImpUrg_Total<9),"Medium",IF(AND(ImpUrg_Total>=9,ImpUrg_Total<13),"Low"))))