# Count occurrences of a particular value in sharepoint folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, microsoft-flow

Trying to either use FLOW or calculated column in sharepoint to try and achieve the following. Appreciate anyones help on this.

God Bless
Janan

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(Values="AA","3",IF(Values="BB","4",IF(Values="CC","1",IF(Values="DD","5",IF(Values="FF","2",IF(Values="WW","6",IF(Values="HH","7","NONE")))))))
```

Test result:

[image]

[SharePoint Calculated Conditional formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)
[SharePoint 2013 calculated column adding multiple if statement](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218662/sharepoint-2013-calculated-column-adding-multiple-if-statement)

**Updated**:

Flow step:
[image]

1

[image]

2

[image]

3

[image]

4

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the above. However, I am not trying to assign a unique value for each item. I would like to count everytime a unique value appears. And the unique value is not limited to this 7, it could expand anytime

Comment: Do you want to count each occurrence of the values column?Or something else？

Comment: yes. Would like to count each occurrence of the values column

Comment: That may only be achieved with flow, use rest to get the number of items with the same value, and then update the current item.Check my update.