# SharePoint 2013 calculated column multiple if statement error

Tags: calculated-column-formula

can you please help me evaluate what is wrong with the if statement below, i need to use it in a SharePoint 2013 calculated column, but I keep getting an error.

```
  =if([Today]-[Last Reviewed Month/Year]<=180,"Green"
        ,if(and([Today]-[Last Reviewed Month/Year]>180,[Today]-[Last Reviewed Month/Year]<365),"Yellow"
           , if([Today] -[Last Reviewed Month/Year])>365,"Red")))
```

Comment: You are having a dead bracket in the end of the calculation.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the formula as below:  **=if([Today]-[Last Reviewed Month/Year]<=180,"Green"
    ,if(and([Today]-[Last Reviewed Month/Year]>180,[Today]-[Last Reviewed Month/Year]<365),"Yellow"
       , if([Today]-[Last Reviewed Month/Year]>365,"Red")))** , but when i saved the page, i got a runtime error instead

Answer (score 0):

1) A calculated column can only use the fields that are given by the GUI. The today keyword must then be referencing to an existing column. I do not think you want to do this, perhaps there is your problem.

2) Depending on the installation/language of your SharePoint environment the parameter seperator must be change from comma "," to semicolumn ";"?

Comment: Hi Bonm014, yes, "Today" is an existing column, and i need to calculate the date difference between [today] and[Last Reviewed Month/Year] ... probably i should use the " datediff" function ...

Answer (score 0):

Common mistake

Today has restrictions in a Formula:

[How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

Your use case will only work if you have a **Workflow** that updates your custom [Today] fied