# Yes No calculated field for closed/created in last 7 days and items open or in-progress

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I would like to create a calculated field that outputs "Yes" or "No" if an item in my SharePoint list has been

1. created in the last 7 days,
2. closed in the last 7 days (field in status column), or 3) displays "Open" or "In-Progress" under the status column.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: You can't do Today calculations in a Calculated Column Formula: see: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported by Microsoft to create calculated columns that references the system date (**TODAY**).

You should look for alternative. My recommendation is to use **JSLink**. It can be useful for painting with a color for example. Or something related to what you need. I leave you a good place to start with jsLink.

[Client-side rendering (JS Link) code samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)