# 2 column validation

Tags: 2013

These are my 2 columns:  Status and Date Closed.  The status column have 2 options; Open or Closed.  What I want to do is if Status = Open, then leave the Date Closed column blank.  But, if the Status = Closed, then the Date closed column equals today's date.  I've tried different ways but no luck so far.  Thanks

Comment: You cannot directly specify today and me in calculated column to set the values. refer this link. this will help you for work around --> https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly this cannot be done using list settings only. The simplest solution in my opinion would be to edit New/Edit form of the list and add Content Editor Web Part with custom javascript code, which would implement required feature. It is rather fast solution, and if you need this on a single list, then it should be just fine.

If you are a fan of Infopath, you can of course use it to achieve required 'flow' as well.

There are also 3rd party applications/tools which can be used to add advanced features to SharePoint forms. One of them is [DFFS](http://spjsblog.com/dffs/), but of course there are many more which can suit your needs.