# Update date calculated column depending of date

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have calculated in a list column who compare dates and return yes or no

Formula: `=TODAY()<[Fieldone]`

So it returns yes or no correctly, problem is when conditioning of date changes because date for example

If today is 24/08/2017  and Fieldone is 25/08/2017 it returns Yes, but if today is 24/08/2017 and Fieldone is 23/08/2017 it need to return Yes, but when date pass it don´t update register automatically. How can I update that value automatically?

Comment: =IF([TodaysDate], "Yes", "No") try this

Comment: I use today() as sharepoint function not column and I compare that date with a column called [fieldone]

Comment: also read: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336

Answer (score 1):

**It's a normal behavior,** The calculated column formula is only calculated/updated In the following cases:

1. Add New Item.
2. Update Existing item.
3. Update the calculated column itself in the list setting!

**So, unfortunately,** you can't update the calculated column value automatically.

For more details check [The supported and unsupported fields in SharePoint calculated column formula](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

---

**The available workaround in SharePoint online is**

Creating a workflow which updates the list items daily via **Retention Policy**

- Check the detail steps at [Automatically update a column with a type of calculated value in a SharePoint List](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/efde4f47-ec3a-4d21-b855-b09b74bc2f6a/automatically-update-a-column-with-a-type-of-calculated-value-in-a-sharepoint-list?forum=sharepointcustomization)

Comment: and with javascript I cant do it? I mean something like my new [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226543/change-column-value-depending-of-comparision-of-dates)

Comment: The above-mentioned is the available solution without code if you need with coding you should try JSLink!

Comment: Or can you show me how can I do workflow step by step in sharepoint online please?

Comment: Using a SharePoint designer, create a simple workflow to update the column value like title value with itself then create a retention policy to start this workflow as mentioned in the above link to run it periodically!

Comment: but without using designer... I mean only using sharepoint online

Comment: No, you can't, there is no OOTB workflow to achieve this,  tell me What's your issue to use SPD?