# How do I make a calculated field with a filter in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, calculated-column-formula

What is wrong with the formula I used:

```
=if([van]>=[today];"[Title]";"")
```

Where, [van] is a date/time field in a calendar.

[Title] is a single line of text.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact requirement of yours?

Comment: Is there any error while creating this field? I guess [TODAY] will not work in calculated formula.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using such a formula? The calculated columns do not update themselves automatically if date (today) is changed. It only updates when you update the item.

Answer (score 1):

The **`[Today]`** is not supported in the Calculated Column. however, to get the current date you can use:

- `TODAY()`, `NOW()` as a **function** that will be returned as DateTime.

For more details check, [The Supported and Unsupported Columns In SharePoint Calculated Column Formula](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference Today in SharePoint's Calculated columns without a workaround. Essentially you have to make a column named "Today" in your list, reference it in your calculated column, then delete the "Today" column to trick SharePoint into referencing the current date. Check out [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/151147/77489) for a better explanation.

If that doesn't work, and assuming the correct syntax for your SharePoint version is a semicolon rather than a comma like mine is, the quotations around [Title] may not be necessary. So try `=if([van]>=[today];[Title];"")` after making the dummy "Today" column.

Once you get the calculated column not error out, then delete the "Today" column and the calculations should work fine.

`EDIT ::`Please note that adding the [Today] field this way does not work as you may expect... The value is *updated* when you modify the list item. It ***does not*** compare to todays actual date, but rather the date of the last time the list item was modified in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **[TODAY]** directly in calculated formula. But there are some **[work arounds](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151147)** to use today in calculated formula.

Once you are done with using one of the workaround for using today. Use below formula:

```
=IF([van]>=[Today], [Title], " ")
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).

   For detailed information and references check my answer given in below link:

   [IF statement with text field isn't possible?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257472/if-statement-with-text-field-isnt-possible/257481)

Comment: He may actually use semi-colon separated functions. Some versions of SharePoint, depending on where you are in the world, have different syntax. Also note that the Today column doesn't stay current. It's only updated when the document or list item has been modified in some way.

Comment: I always use comma in IF condition, see [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a). Also today is not a column, he need to use one of the workaround for today as given in work around link in my answer.

Comment: If you're using the danish regional setting, according to [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052261/10210195) then you need to use semicolons instead of commas since the comma is a decimal separator. I assume there's other languages that have the same style of formatting as the danish, so don't rule out other language syntaxes. And correct, the Today does need a work around but SharePoint won't update it all the time. The values in Calculated columns are re-calculated when the item is modified.

Comment: have you tried this?