# Attempting to get a Calculated Column to output Yes/No (Formula)

Tags: calculated-column, formula

I am trying to make a calculated column produce a Yes/No when:

```
IF([Reminder Date]= [Today], “Yes”)
```

and

```
IF([Reminder Date] does not equal [Today], “No”)
```

What is the correct formula?

Answer (score 0):

The IF has 3 arguments, so:

IF(A, B, C)

- where A is a boolean expression
- B is what's returned if A is true and
- C is what's returned if A is false

So if you want something like:

```
=IF([Reminder Date]=[Today], "Yes", "No")
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic syntax for IF statement in calculated formula is:

```
IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)
```

So, try to write down your formula in above format.

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).

   For detailed information and references check my answer given in below link:

   [IF statement with text field isn't possible?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257472/if-statement-with-text-field-isnt-possible/257481)
2. Sometimes, The **[Today]** is not supported in the Calculated Column. Check below work arounds before using `Today` in your formula.

   - [How do I make a calculated field with a filter in SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251955/how-do-i-make-a-calculated-field-with-a-filter-in-sharepoint-2010/251958)
   - [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column)

Comment: have you tried this?