# Calculated Date formula not updating?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date

We have a Custom List in SP Online which pertains to parts needing to be inspected. Our list has the following fields:

- LAST-INSP: a manually entered date showing when the part was last inspected.
- FREQ-IN-DAYS: frequency of inspection, manually entered by the Quality staff.
- NEXT-INSP: a calcuated field as:  =[LAST-INSP]+[FREQ-IN-DAYS]
- INSP-DUE: a calculated field as:  =[NEXT-INSP]<=TODAY()

Normally this works as expected, but sometimes we see a "glitch" where the Inspection Due field does not change. For example, today I looked and found this

[image]

The highlighted row SHOULD have the INSP-DUE field set to YES because the Next Inspection date is equal to today, but it's not updating properly.

Is there a known issue with calculated fields? Is there something I'm missing in my formula? Is the date field using local vs. UTC date/time? Is there a parameter in SP Online for calculated fields that I need to check?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

gpence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a normal behavior,  The calculated column formula is **only** calculated/updated in the following cases:

- Add New Item.
- Update Existing item.
- Update the calculated column itself in the List Setting!

Check also, [The Supported and Unsupported Columns In SharePoint Calculated fields](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thank you, Mohamed. Let me also ask this for clarification purposes: When you say "Add a New Item" or "Update Existing Item" -- are only those records recalculated, or are all rows in the list recalculated? Also, is it possible to create a Flow to force the column to update all records on a daily basis?

Comment: Only this record will be recalculated, flow and sharepoint designer workflow is only applied on the current row, not a column.

Comment: For more background info see: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336