# Showings days past due and days until due in same field

Tags: custom-list, calculated-column-formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(NOW(), [Renewal Date], "d")), -DATEDIF([Renewal Date], TODAY(), "d"))
```

I am using the formula above and this is correctly showing me the items that are past due and for items that are current I am getting a message of No. I want the field to show how many days until the item is due by showing a negative number.

The formula I use in excel is

```
=IF(H3<>"", TODAY()-H3, TODAY()-F3)
```

Comment: Note Today does not update!! See https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple way how to achieve it:

- create SharePoint Calculated column
- formula: `=[Renewal Date]-TODAY()`
- outcome: Number, decimal places: 0

[image]