# SharePoint Calculated Column to Show Date Help

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I have a column "Status" and when "Completed" is chosen from the dropdown, I'd like a calculated column to show the date of that day.  Is that possible with an 'If And" statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new column named Today
and then create calculated column as below:
=IF([Status]="Completed",[Today],"")

Delete the Today column created earlier and it will work as expected i.e. whenever Status is Completed,Calculated column will show Today's date
[image]

Comment: interesting workaround!  Thanks

Comment: But wait 24 hours and your TODAY trick doesn't work....You might want to read https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336