# Calculated Date column to determine if 30 days has passed

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a column "Document Date" which is manually entered. I would like to create a calculated column that defaults to "Yes", unless it's 30 days after the document date in which case it automatically turns to "No".

Is this possible within the confines of calculated columns? or will this require a workflow.

I'm using SharePoint 2013 on prem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the answer for this.

```
=IF(DATEDIF([Document Date],NOW(),"d")>30,"No","Yes")
```

With The data type returned from this formula as: 
    **Single line of text**

Comment: But ``NOW()`` only updates when the item is saved/updated. So wait 24 hours and your formula is wrong: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column