# Calculate number of days from date to today

Tags: 2016, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have tried and looked for the answer to calculate the number of days from a date to  today's date and getting an error.

> Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like:

```
=TODAY()-RequestedDate
```

Comment: It worked,  thank you